# C# OrderBy used by Func Expression

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, nullreferenceexception, linq-expressions

Hi I am having problem with this expressions:

1. I am creating List of two expression for OrderBy(orderby(first from list).thenby(second from list)), but in some cases Recipient can be null.

```
List<Expression<Func<Data, dynamic>>> orderingExpression = new List<Expression<Func<Data, dynamic>>>();
orderingExpression.Add(x => (x.Inhalt.Recipient == null && x.Inhalt.Recipient.Address == null) ? null : x.Inhalt.Recipient.Address.Nummer);

orderingExpression.Add(x => (x.Inhalt.Recipient == null && x.Inhalt.Recipient.Address == null) ? null : x.Inhalt.Recipient.Address.Street);
```

2. Later in code I am using it like this:

```
datatemp = datatemp.OrderBy(orderingExpression.First()).ThenBy(orderingExpression.Last());
```

but even when I have null check in step 1 for both expressions still getting "object reference not set to an instance"
Other values which has Recipient are sorted correctly.

I tried to use string.Empty instead of null in ternary operator but still same problem.

Do I need to write null check in some different way?

Comment: You are checking if `Recipient` is null **and** if `Recipient.Address` is null.  And that second check you are only performing if `Recipient` is null, thus guaranteeing an NRE.  Also why are you using `dynamic`?

Comment: what happens when you try `orderingExpression.Add(x => x?.Inhalt?.Recipient?.Address?.Nummer ?? xxx);orderingExpression.Add(x => x?.Inhalt?.Recipient?.Address?.Street ?? yyy);` while xxx and yyy have to be replaced by some meaningfull default values...

Comment: @KirkWoll true when I removed Recipient.Address it works now..but Is it possible to add somehow also check for Recipient.Address? dynamic is used because from some other places in code I will need datatemp orderby(string,decimal,int ...etc.)

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 in that case I got **"An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator"**

Comment: @KirkWoll ok I changed condition to `x.Inhalt.Recipient != null && x.Inhalt.Recipient.Address != null` and its ok now thanks